# mongoDB complex query to find sum of inner document list

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to build an application based on mongoDB and get stuck in one usecase.
I want to find sum of document between specific date range. Below is my sample collection.

```js
db.matrix.findOne()

{
    "_id": "varun_2013-06-06",
    "loginId": "varun",
    "date": ISODate("2013-06-05T18:30:00Z"),
    "headers": [{
            "header": "header1"
            "time": 2,
            "detail": "x"
        }, {
            "header": header2 "time": 4,
            "detail": "y"
        }, {
            "header": "header3"
            "time": 6,
            "detail": "z"
        }, {
            "header": "header4",
            "time": 9,
            "detail": "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

So for specific range my query should give total sum of each header.
like fromDate to toDate 
header1 = 40hr header2 = 60hr and so on....

Can anyone help me to find query for this use case in mongodb.  I am using mongoTemplate in spring. and `{ "header" : "header1" "time" : 2, "detail" : "x" }` is a `List<T>` inside Main class

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using? if you are on 2.2+ you should use the aggregation framework for this.

Comment: Yes , I am using 2.2.  Can you help me to find how can I achieve this using aggregation framework?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation pipeline you need is something like this:

```
var startDate = new ISODate(...);
var endDate = new ISODate(...);

col.aggregate([  
  // filter by date range
  { $match: { date: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } },

  // unwind embedded headers collection so we have one item per header
  { $unwind: '$headers' },

  // group by header and output a total
  { $group: { _id: '$headers.header', total: { sum: 1 } }
]);
```

I don't know how to do this in Spring but it should be pretty much the same, assuming Spring supports the Aggregation Framework.

Please also note that if the amount of data is large, you'll need an appropriate index to support this (e.g. an index on `date` or possibly on `date` + `headers.header`).